# Custom Header problem with axios inside Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, cors, xmlhttprequest, axios

I am trying to hit the login API with Custom header. First I got CORS error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'URL' from origin 'http://localhost:3000'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
>   pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource

Then I disabled CORS by NO CORS Plugin. Now Im getting:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'URL' from origin 'http://localhost:3000'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
>   pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Below is my code:

````
    const userDetails = { email, password };

    let data = JSON.stringify({ 
          request : {
                    ascUser : 
                      {
                        userName : "xxx@sample.com",
                        password : "12345678"
                      }
                    }
    })
    return dispatch => {

      axios.request('URL', {data:data},
        {headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-transId' : '****',
        'x-channel-id' : '***' 
      }}
      )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
          if(res.error) {
              throw(res.error);
          }
          dispatch(
            userLogin({
            ...userDetails
          })
        );
          return res.products;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      }
      ) 
  };
}```
````

Comment: Enable CORS on your backend application. If you are using express, refer this https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: What is the NO CORS Plugin? Something client or server side?

Comment: is there any other way to do it without disabling the CORS in backend?Because its working fine in Android and POSTMAN.

Comment: NO CORS Extension for chrome

Comment: It is working on postman or any other non-web software because CORS only applied to browsers. I's a security behavior you can disable client side.

Comment: @SaranKumar is the backend express application?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors, on the backend (at your nodejs server maybe)

1. `npm i cors --save`

2.

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()    
app.use(cors())
```

Comment: Header is not being set properly.Is there  anything to do with Redux?

Comment: it has to do with cors not REDUX, follow my example and give me your feedback

Comment: The problem is its third party API.So,Im trying to solve it from client side.

Comment: you can't solve it from the client, it is IMPOSSIBLE. The backend has implemented the cors to the **origin** 'http://localhost:3000'.
Feel free to upvote other answers, but none will work in the browser :)